# Create events in PHPMyAdmin to insert a user every hour

Tags: phpmyadmin

I'm trying to create an event from the PHPMyAdmin interface.

I created the event, Status is enabled, set to Scheduled every 1 hour. But it's not working.

In Events, "Event scheduler status" is set to Off, when I try to set it On, I get this error:
Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation

I'm not sure if I have to turn ON this trigger and how.

I'm a user with all privileges enabled.

My questions:

Should I set the "Event scheduler status" to ON to run the events ?
How can I set myself to Superuser while I have all privileges ?

Thank you for your advises.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you need to set the scheduler to ON. I doubt that your MySQL account has the Super privilege, which is global. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privileges-provided.html.

Comment: I have access to cPanel, when I created my database and MySQL user in cPanel, I checked all privileges. How do I give myself superuser privileges ?

Comment: The privileges you see are probably database-specific privileges. You would need global privileges but most likely, your host provider does not allow that.

Comment: I have access to cPanel VPS server. Any idea how to upgrade the user to superuser ?

Comment: Ask your hosting provider.